Как указать NULL or string в Doctrine Database Abstraction Layer (DBAL)
Использую Symfony 7.4.1
Есть метод:
...
use Doctrine\DBAL\Connection;
use Doctrine\DBAL\ParameterType;
...

public function setImages(int $post_id, ?string $images_str): void
{
   $this->connection->executeStatement("UPDATE `blog_posts` SET `images` = ? WHERE `id` = ?", [$images_str, $post_id], [ParameterType::STRING||ParameterType::NULL, ParameterType::INTEGER]);
}

Параметр $images_str может быть строкой или NULL. Как правильно указать строка или NULL?
Так правильно:
ParameterType::STRING||ParameterType::NULL

